# Is (or can) nodejs http server replacement for big servers like Apache or IIS

Tags: javascript, node.js, apache, iis

I am new to web-technologies so please bear with me.

Is HTTP server you create in node.js is (or can be) total replacement for Apache or IIS?

How does someone usually approach when they want to deploy their Node.js application on the web?

Note that, I am not asking about where and how to host but whether creating an HTTP server in Node.js replaces APACHE or IIS completely? How does big organization like Yahoo or LinkedIn who are using Node.js do it when they want to host their Node.js application? Do you have to rely on different web-server Apache when you want to host large Node.js application?

I am also asking this because my application is partially written on Node.js and partially on C#. So in this case, If I want to use anything like edge.js to run a C# application in Node.js, what should I choose as web-server- IIS or Node.js HTTP server (which might be just 50 lines of code)?

Comment: Anybody who voted to close, I don't really mind but this question is really important to me. I am asking because I cannot find anything useful in internet (Trust me).

Comment: The reason you are receiving close votes is because non of these questions are particularly suitable for StackOverflow in that there isn't a clear right or wrong answer, it comes down to the opinion of the answerer. You'd be better off asking at a forum more suited to open ended discussion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Can it replace my webserver?

Yes, node's `http` module can be used to **BUILD** a complete replacement for utilities like Apache or IIS. Notice the emphasis on the word build. It takes some work to make it mature and robust enough to compete with battle tested web servers and therefore you shouldn't consider is a complete drop in replacement out-of-the-box. However, a framework like `express` can help introduce the typical features deployed in mature webservers to get you there faster.

### How do Enterprise companies handle?:

I can't speak to how Yahoo! handles their node servers, but I know LinkedIn uses `nginx` for both static file serving and load balancing between many clusters of node apps. See this article from their engineering team for some best practices: http://engineering.linkedin.com/nodejs/blazing-fast-nodejs-10-performance-tips-linkedin-mobile